# Precomputation attacks against ECDH

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, number-field-sieve

Diffie-Hellman groups are vulnerable to [sieving precomputation attacks](https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy-ccs15.pdf). These attacks allow a one-time computation against a given DH modulus that makes it practical to attack all subsequent key negotiation operations using the same group. It is speculated that, at least in 2015, it takes only $8M USD to build ASICs capable of performing this initial precomputation stage for any 1024-bit group in a single year.<sup>*</sup>

Section 5 of the above paper mentions that ECDH is merely *less* vulnerable to precomputation:

> Transitioning to elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) key exchange with appropriate parameters avoids all known feasible cryptanalytic attacks. Current elliptic curve discrete log algorithms for strong curves do not gain **as much of an advantage** from precomputation.

Emphasis mine. This implies that these attacks *can* be used against ECDH, albeit with less benefit, despite the fact that ECDH is not run over a multiplicative group of integers modulo a prime, which precomputation exploits. I have three questions about these attacks and how they apply to ECDH:

1. How can ECDH be attacked if it uses multiplicative groups of points on a curve?
2. How much of an advantage does an attacker gain from said precomputation?
3. Does the choice or class of curve have any impact on the feasibility of this attack?

<sup>* On a side-note, I'm skeptical that this cost estimate is accurate, since the authors of the paper assume that consumer SDRAM (in terms of price and access behavior) will be used instead of high-speed VIAs or other custom constructions.</sup>

Comment: The cheapest attack is some kind of parallel batch $\rho$, unless you have a special case in front of you, like pairing-friendly curves where it'll be a tossup between $\rho$ and index calculus.  I'm not aware of any precomputation that reduces the net _cost_ of a generic $\rho$ attack.